# Splitcontainer, Make a fixed panel

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, splitcontainer

I have a splitcontainer with horizontal orientation.

I want a fixed height for panel2 only during form resize, and let splitter resize panel2

Now I'm doing it this way, but I'm not satisfy because user notice that the panel resize

```
Private Sub Form1_ResizeBegin(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles Me.ResizeBegin 
    spil = SplitContainer1.Height - SplitContainer1.SplitterDistance
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_ResizeEnd(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles Me.ResizeEnd
    SplitContainer1.SplitterDistance = SplitContainer1.Height - spil
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried setting SplitContainer1.FixedPanel = Panel1 (and removing both events) ?

Comment: It was not in the property list in designer :) Thanks!